# How to create an array in python to store elements of certain type like integers, characters ..?

Tags: python, arrays

```
i <- 0
count <- 0
for (i in 1:length(t4))
 {
   if ((t4[i] != "OK" || t4[i] !="") && (t4[i] != t2[i]))
    {
      count = count + 1  
      x[count] <- t2[i]
      z[count] <- t4[i]
    }
 }
```

## to run this code in python i needed an array, hence is my question

Comment: What makes you say you want an array? What particular properties are you looking for that are different from the behavior of Python lists, and why?

Comment: The fact that you're specifically calling it an "array" without seeming to be familiar with the Python data structures referred to as "arrays" suggests that you may be pulling in preconceptions or definitions from other languages, which may not be appropriate to Python.

Comment: @user2357112 Or he wants optimal performance for a specific data type. Or wants to restrict it to a specific type of elements. In case of performance: That's where NumPy comes in. Unfortunatly there is no use-case given so it's hard to give a specific recommendation for the data structure to choose.

Comment: @user2357112 i have edited my body of question, u can have a look

Comment: @DavidGladson: Lists would work fine for that (and also I see at least one bug - `t4[i] != "OK" || t4[i] !=""` is always true). You could rewrite it to take advantage of the benefits of NumPy arrays, but I'd recommend getting the basics down first.

Comment: @DavidGladson Better to ask a new question and roll back this one in that case. A new question will attract more attention and more suitable answers (and you won't invalidate existing answers to this question).

Comment: @user2357112 where can i get the basics about working with data frames in pandas python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/array.html#module-array):

```
from array import array

array('i', [10, 20])   # "i" represents "signed int" type
```

or if you have NumPy then [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.array([10, 20])
```

However in most cases mixed-type `list`s should be good enough.

Comment: Thanks, and how to specify the size?

Comment: with NumPy for example: `np.empty(size, dtype='int32')`. With the `array.array` and `numpy.array` functions you create an array that's just big enough to contain the data you give it. In your example both will create a size 2 array.

Comment: @DavidGladson No problem! Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer :)

Comment: @DavidGladson But I just want to stress the last sentence of my answer again: In most cases `list`s are good enough - in some cases they might be even better. :)